# Mask outside of an interval of Two 2D array?

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I have one 3D array, i.e. `param`:

```
param.shape = (20, 50, 50)
```

I want to mask its first axis outside of one interval, i.e. two 2D arrays, `bot` and `top`:

```
bot.shape = (50, 50)
top.shape = (50, 50)
```

What I have tried is:

```
bot_n = np.broadcast_to(bot[0, :, :], param.shape)
top_n = np.broadcast_to(top[0, :, :], param.shape)
output =  np.ma.masked_outside(param, bot_n, top_n)
```

But I got the following error:

> if v2 < v1:
>   ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

In fact, I want to extract the value of `param` which is between `bot` and `top` values.

Answer (score 0):

You could construct the mask yourself:

```
output = np.ma.array(param, (param < bot_n) & (param > top_n))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for `masked_outside` is quite simple:

```
if v2 < v1:
    (v1, v2) = (v2, v1)
xf = filled(x)
condition = (xf < v1) | (xf > v2)
return masked_where(condition, x, copy=copy)
```

The `condition1` expression should work with your array `bot_n`, but the `if v2<v1` test only works with scalar limits.  The function author was thinking of a simple `[3, 9]` interval, not your more general 2d one.

So, yes, write your own mask.